# How can I get the texture file name for my polygon?

Tags: opengl, c++, fbx

I have a problem with the FBX SDK. I read in the data for the vertex position and the UV coordinates. It works fine, but now I want to read for each polygon to which texture it belongs, so that I can have models with multiple textures. Can anyone tell me how I can get the texture file name for my polygon? My code to read in vertex position and uv coordinates is the following:

```
int i, j, lPolygonCount = pMesh->GetPolygonCount();
FbxVector4* lControlPoints = pMesh->GetControlPoints(); 

int vertexId = 0;
for (i = 0; i < lPolygonCount; i++)
{

    int lPolygonSize = pMesh->GetPolygonSize(i);

    for (j = 0; j < lPolygonSize; j++)
    {
        int lControlPointIndex = pMesh->GetPolygonVertex(i, j);
        FbxVector4 pos = lControlPoints[lControlPointIndex];
        current_model[vertex_index].x = pos.mData[0] - pivot_offset[0];
        current_model[vertex_index].y = pos.mData[1] - pivot_offset[1];
        current_model[vertex_index].z = pos.mData[2]- pivot_offset[2];

        FbxVector4 vertex_normal;
        pMesh->GetPolygonVertexNormal(i,j, vertex_normal);  

        current_model[vertex_index].nx = vertex_normal.mData[0];
        current_model[vertex_index].ny = vertex_normal.mData[1];
        current_model[vertex_index].nz = vertex_normal.mData[2];

        //read in UV data
        FbxStringList lUVSetNameList;
        pMesh->GetUVSetNames(lUVSetNameList);

        //get lUVSetIndex-th uv set
        const char* lUVSetName = lUVSetNameList.GetStringAt(0);
        const FbxGeometryElementUV* lUVElement = pMesh->GetElementUV(lUVSetName);

        if(!lUVElement)
            continue;

            // only support mapping mode eByPolygonVertex and eByControlPoint
        if( lUVElement->GetMappingMode() != FbxGeometryElement::eByPolygonVertex &&
            lUVElement->GetMappingMode() != FbxGeometryElement::eByControlPoint )
            return;

        //index array, where holds the index referenced to the uv data
        const bool lUseIndex 
            = lUVElement->GetReferenceMode() != FbxGeometryElement::eDirect;
        const int lIndexCount= (lUseIndex) ? lUVElement->GetIndexArray().GetCount() : 0;

        FbxVector2 lUVValue;

        //get the index of the current vertex in control points array
        int lPolyVertIndex = pMesh->GetPolygonVertex(i,j);

        //the UV index depends on the reference mode
        int lUVIndex = pMesh->GetTextureUVIndex(i, j);
        lUVValue = lUVElement->GetDirectArray().GetAt(lUVIndex);
        current_model[vertex_index].tu = (float)lUVValue.mData[0];
        current_model[vertex_index].tv = (float)lUVValue.mData[1];


        vertex_index ++;
        }

    }

    float v1[3], v2[3], v3[3];
    v1[0] = current_model[vertex_index - 3].x;
    v1[1] = current_model[vertex_index - 3].y;
    v1[2] = current_model[vertex_index - 3].z;

    v2[0] = current_model[vertex_index - 2].x;
    v2[1] = current_model[vertex_index - 2].y;
    v2[2] = current_model[vertex_index - 2].z;

    v3[0] = current_model[vertex_index - 1].x;
    v3[1] = current_model[vertex_index - 1].y;
    v3[2] = current_model[vertex_index - 1].z;

    collision_model->addTriangle(v1,v2,v3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the the texture information by following steps,

FbxNode -> FbxSurfaceMaterial -> FbxLayeredTexture or FbxTexture -> Texture name (and other properties)

The code looks like,

```
int mcount = node->GetSrcObjectCount<FbxSurfaceMaterial>();
for (int index=0; index<mcount; index++ )
{
   FbxSurfaceMaterial *material = (FbxSurfaceMaterial*)node->GetSrcObject<FbxSurfaceMaterial>(index);
   if (material)
   {
      // This only gets the material of type sDiffuse, you probably need to traverse all Standard Material Property by its name to get all possible textures.
      FbxProperty prop = material->FindProperty(FbxSurfaceMaterial::sDiffuse);

      // Check if it's layeredtextures
      int layered_texture_count = prop.GetSrcObjectCount<FbxLayeredTexture>();
      if (layered_texture_count > 0)
      {
         for (int j=0; j < layered_texture_count; j++)
         {
            FbxLayeredTexture* layered_texture = FbxCast<FbxLayeredTexture>(prop.GetSrcObject<FbxLayeredTexture>(j));
            int lcount = layered_texture->GetSrcObjectCount<FbxTexture>();
            for (int k=0; k<lcount; k++)
            {
               FbxTexture* texture = FbxCast<FbxTexture>(layered_texture->GetSrcObject<FbxTexture>(k));
               // Then, you can get all the properties of the texture, include its name
               const char* texture_name = texture->GetName();
            }
         }
      }
      else 
      {
         // Directly get textures
         int texture_count = prop.GetSrcObjectCount<FbxTexture>();
         for (int j=0; j<texture_count; j++)
         {
            const FbxTexture* texture = FbxCast<FbxTexture>(prop.GetSrcObject<FbxTexture>(j));
            // Then, you can get all the properties of the texture, include its name
            const char* texture_name = texture->GetName();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's lproperty?

Comment: Sorry, a typo here, should be the variable prop, not lproperty.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell FBX SDK specification from what you linked but that's how this data is stored in your FBX file, for instance:

- "Cube" - mesh object
- "Logo.png" - texture

FBX contains section called "Connections" which looks like this:

```
; Object connections
;------------------------------------------------------------------

Connections:  { 
    Connect: "OO", "Model::Cube", "Model::Scene"
    Connect: "OO", "Material::Material__Logo_png", "Model::Cube"
    Connect: "OO", "Texture::Logo_png", "Model::Cube"
    Connect: "OO", "Video::Logo_png", "Texture::Logo_png"
}
```

FBX files can either be binary or ASCII and either contain paths to textures or having textures packed inside. You can use [FBX Converter 2013](http://www.autodesk.mx/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=10775855) by Autodek to switch and pack/unpack textures.

Comment: but I have more textures per model.

Comment: Then you will have multiple "connections" to one mesh object.