# FBX SDK texture file name

Tags: c++, directx, fbx

I have built an importer that retrieves necessary vertex data however I wish to be able to read texture file directories. How do I retrieve the texture file name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the texture file name for my polygon?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54095/how-can-i-get-the-texture-file-name-for-my-polygon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FBX supports a whole range of texture *properties* per surface material: diffuse, specular, etc.. The *property name*s are stored in static char* fields in SDK classs *FbxSurfaceMaterial*. You can get a pointer to such a material by iterating across all materials of an *FbxNode* using functions *GetMaterialCount()* and *GetMaterial(index)*.

To load a texture, you first have to retrieve a valid *FbxProperty* from the *FbxSurfaceMaterial* by querying it with *FindProperty(propertyName)*, then iterate over the number of "SrcObjects" using *GetSrcObjectCount()* and *GetSrcObject()*  and for each of them retrieve the user data with GetUserDataPtr(). This user data contains the name of the texture. How you map that to your filesystem/packed data/ is up to you.

Keep in mind that most of the properties also have associated factor properties, and they can be queried with their associated names in exactly the same way. The factors are typically used to set material property weights in the lighting shader (such as specular, reflectiveness, ambient, emissive etc.. )

Comment: Cheers! The SDK can be so damn confusing.